# Android Clean MVVM With Dagger 2

Tags: android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2, android-mvvm

I've just got back to the Java&Android world.
In my search for a good project starters that will leverage compilation time DI and MvvM, I found these two:

1. [Writing Testable Android MVVM](https://medium.com/@hiBrianLee/writing-testable-android-mvvm-app-prelude-e49f7e6223)
2. [Countries - A sample Android app](https://github.com/patloew/countries)

Now to my problem...
I'd like to make a base activity looks like this (keeping the important parts):

```
public abstract class ViewModelActivity<VM extends IViewModel> extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityComponent activityComponent;
@Inject
private VM viewModel;

protected void inject(AppComponent appComponent) {
    appComponent.inject(this);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    AppComponent appComponent = ((MvvmApplication) getApplication()).getAppComponent();
    inject(appComponent);

    activityComponent =
            DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
            .appComponent(appComponent)
            .activityModule(new ActivityModule(this))
            .build();

    ViewModel.State savedViewModelState = null;
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        savedViewModelState = savedInstanceState.getParcelable(EXTRA_VIEW_MODEL_STATE);
    }
    viewModel = createViewModel(savedViewModelState);
}

}
```

And so my AppComponent should look like:

```
@AppScope
@Component(modules = {
    AppContextModule.class,
    AppModule.class,
    NetworkModule.class,
    GsonModule.class
})
public interface MyAppComponent extends AppComponent {

    void inject(DashboardActivity baseActivity);

    Picasso picasso();

}
```

Where AppComponent is:

```
@AppScope
public interface AppComponent {

    Context appContext();

    void inject(ViewModelActivity viewModelActivity);

}
```

And finally the concrete Activity is:

```
public class DashboardActivity extends ViewModelActivity<DashboardViewModel> {}
```

Now I keep getting the following error:

```
Error:(29, 10) error: activities.dashboard.DashboardViewModel cannot be 
provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-
annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be 
implicitly provided.
activities.dashboard.DashboardViewModel is injected at
mvvm.activity.ViewModelActivity.viewModel
activities.dashboard.DashboardActivity is injected at
app.inject(baseActivity)
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: The error says that this class ``activities.dashboard.DashboardViewModel`` has to either have an annotated constructor with ``@Inject``, or that you need to have a ``@Provides`` method in one of your modules that provides said class. So have you done any of these?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided \[...\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided)

Comment: In `DashboardViewModel`'s constructor function, add @Inject on top. That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

To use MVVM with dagger check out [this sample code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/tree/master/GithubBrowserSample) from google

It really did it very well and it uses the latest trends in dagger as well, like defining submodules and using new `AndroidInjection` for injecting activities and fragments. It also uses a custom factory for creating your view model that takes care of injecting the constructor fields.

Comment: But this project has developped with Kotlin.