# How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided [...]'?

Tags: java, dagger-2

> This is a [Canonical Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/291992/1837367) because this is a common error with Dagger 2.
>
> *If your question was flagged as a duplicate* please read this post carefully *and make sure to understand what this error means and why it occured. If this post does not work for you make sure to include* where *and* how *you provide the mentioned classes and include the* full error message *in your question like the one here.*

I tried to use a dependency with Dagger 2, but I receive the following error when I try to compile my project:

> **error:** com.example.*MyDependency* cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
>
> com.example.*MyDependency* is provided at
>   com.example.MyComponent.myDependency()

What does this mean and how can I fix it?

I have a component and tried to provide a dependency. My basic setup looks like this:

```
// this is the dependency I try to use
class MyDependency {}

@Component
interface MyComponent {
    // I want to make it accessible to be used with my component
    MyDependency myDependency();
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**tl;dr** You forgot to either add an `@Inject` to your constructor so that Dagger can use Constructor Injection to provide the object, or you need some method in one of your Modules that creates or binds the object.

---

### What's going on?

Have a good look at the error message: It states that you try to request a dependency but **Dagger has no way to provide or create it**. It simply does not know how to, because it *cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.*

A close look at the error message shows the class **(a)** that you are trying to provide and the component **(b)** that needs it.

> com.example.MyDependency **(a)** is provided at
>   com.example.MyComponent.myDependency() **(b)**

You have to make sure that **(b)** can create or provide **(a)** to fix your issue.

It looks a bit more complex if you tried to inject your dependency somewhere else, but you can still see the full stack of events—in this case a constructor injection missing a dependency. The class **(a)** that you are trying to provide and the location **(b)** where Dagger tried injecting it. It also tells you where that dependent class was created **(c)** and again the component **(d)** that failed providing **(a)**.

> com.example.MyDependency cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
>   com.example.MyDependency **(a)** is injected at
>   com.example.DependentClass.(dependency) **(b)**
>   com.example.DependentClass is provided at **(c)**
>   com.example.MyComponent.myDependency() **(d)**

The same applies here: Make sure that **(d)** knows how to provide **(a)** and you're good to go.

### How do I fix this?

Have a look at the error as shown above. Make sure you understand *where* it occured and *what* you are trying to inject. Then tell Dagger how to provide your object.

#### an @Inject constructor

As the error states, you try to use `MyDependency` but `MyComponent` does not know how to do that. If we have a look at the example it becomes clear why:

```
class MyDependency {}
```

The class has *no `@Inject` annotated constructor*! And there is no other module in the component, so there is nothing Dagger could do.

If you want to use constructor injection you can just **add an `@Inject` annotated constructor** and are done. Dagger will see this constructor and know how to create your class.

```
class MyDependency {
    @Inject
    MyDependency() { /**/ }
}
```

That is all you have to do when you can make use of constructor injection.

#### from an @Provides-annotated method

The error message states a second option, which allows you to provide an object if you don't want—or can't—use constructor injection. You can also **add a `@Provides` annotated method** to a module and add this module to your component.

```
@Module
class MyModule {
    @Provides
    MyDependency provideMyDependency() {
        return new MyDependency();
    }
}

@Component(modules = MyModule.class)
interface MyComponent {
    MyDependency myDependency();
}
```

This way Dagger can use your module to create and provide your dependency. It is a little bit more boilerplate than using Constructor Injection, but you will have to use Modules for everything that needs further setup or that does not have an annotated constructor, e.g. third party libraries like Retrofit, OkHttp, or Gson.

---

There are also other ways to provide a dependency from a component. A `@SubComponent` has access to its parents dependencies, and a component dependency can expose some of its dependencies to its dependent components. But at some point everything Dagger provides needs to either have an `@Inject` constructor or a Module providing it.

### But I did add `MyDependency`!

**Pay close attention to the details.** You probably are using an interface when you are only providing the implementation, or try to use a parent class when Dagger only knows about the subclass.
Maybe you added a custom `@Qualifier` or used `@Named("typeA")` with it. To Dagger this is a completely different object! Double check that you actually provide and request the same dependency.

Read the error and make sure that you either have an `@Inject` annotated constructor, a module that has a `@Provides` method that *provides that type*, or a parent component that does.

#### What if I want to provide an implementation for my interface?

A simple example like the following shows how one class extends another:

```
class MyDependency extends MyBaseDependency {
    @Inject MyDependency() { super(); }
}
```

This will inform Dagger about `MyDependency`, **but not about `MyBaseDependency`.**

If you have one class implementing an interface or extending a super class you have to declare that. If you provide `MyDependency` this does not mean that Dagger can provide `MyBaseDependency`. You can use `@Binds` to tell Dagger about your implementation and provide it when the super class is required.

```
@Module
interface MyModule {
    @Binds
    MyBaseDependency provideMyBaseDependency(MyDependency implementation);
}
```

Comment: Nicely written!

Comment: When setting up implementation of an interface  using Binds, Do you still need to create the @Provides method for the interface to return the implementation?

Comment: @jonney No, you won't need an additional `@Provides`. `@Binds` will also provide the implementation / interface.

Comment: "Pay close attention to the details" was key for me. @Named was my issue propagating my dependency. I had ServerModule which created retrofit, and a ServerApiModule that depended on it. Thanks!

Comment: This is a real old answer but had such an important clue about injecting interfaces! Dagger 2 errors haven't changed even by 2021.