# Dagger2 Compilation Issue in kotlin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2, dagger

I am trying to learn dependency injection using Dagger2. I have created few custom scopes and Qualifier. I have created an application component where I wanted to inject certain global dependencies and also I have created an Activity component which will return certain instances based upon activity context.

Now when I try to inject global instances in the Activity I am getting error as follows:

> e:
>   /home/arifur/source_code/me/myprojects/Learn/studio/Android/kotlin/FirebaseChat/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/arifur/firebasechatkotlin/dependecies/component/ActivityComponent.java:7:
>   error: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth cannot be provided
>   without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method. e:
>
> e:     public abstract void
>   inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull() e:
>   ^ e:       com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is injected at e:
>   com.example.arifur.firebasechatkotlin.BaseActivity.firebaseAuth e:
>   com.example.arifur.firebasechatkotlin.MainActivity is injected at e:
>   com.example.arifur.firebasechatkotlin.dependecies.component.ActivityComponent.inject(p0)
>
> w: warning: The following options were not recognized by any
>   processor: '[kapt.kotlin.generated]' w:
>
> e:
>   /home/arifur/source_code/me/myprojects/Learn/studio/Android/kotlin/FirebaseChat/app/src/main/java/com/example/arifur/firebasechatkotlin/BaseActivity.kt:
>   (29, 9): Unresolved reference: DaggerActivityComponent e:
>   /home/arifur/source_code/me/myprojects/Learn/studio/Android/kotlin/FirebaseChat/app/src/main/java/com/example/arifur/firebasechatkotlin/FirebaseChatApp.kt:
>   (20, 13): Unresolved reference: DaggerFirebaseComponent e:
>   /home/arifur/source_code/me/myprojects/Learn/studio/Android/kotlin/FirebaseChat/app/src/main/java/com/example/arifur/firebasechatkotlin/MainActivity.kt:
>   (1, 1): Some error(s) occurred while processing annotations. Please
>   see the error messages above.

---

### Qualifiers

***ActivityContext.kt***

```
@Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ActivityContext
```

***ApplicationContext.kt***

```
@javax.inject.Qualifier
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
annotation class ApplicationContext
```

---

### Scopes

***ActivityScope.kt***

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class ApplicationScope
```

***ApplicationScope.kt***

```
@Scope
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.SOURCE)
annotation class ApplicationScope
```

---

### Components

***ActivityComponent.kt*** Used in Injecting Activity class.

```
@ActivityScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class), dependencies = arrayOf(FirebaseComponent::class))
interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(mainActivity: MainActivity)
}
```

***FirebaseComponent.kt*** Used in injecting Application class.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class, FirebaseAuthModule::class, NetworkModule::class))
interface FirebaseComponent {
    fun inject(app: FirebaseChatApp)
}
```

---

### Modules

***ActivityModule.kt***

```
@Module
class ActivityModule(val activity : Activity) {
    var mActivityRef : WeakReference<Activity> ;
    init {
        mActivityRef = WeakReference<Activity>(activity)
    }

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    @ActivityContext
    public fun getActivityContext() : Context? = mActivityRef.get()

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    @ActivityContext
    public fun getActivityInstance() : Activity? = mActivityRef.get();


    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    public fun getGlideActivityInstance(@ActivityContext context : Context?) : Glide {
        Log.i("activityModule", "Returning activity glide")
        return Glide.get(context);
    }

}
```

***ApplicationModule.kt***

```
@Module
class ApplicationModule(val app : FirebaseChatApp) {

    @ApplicationContext
    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    fun provideContext() : Context = app


    @ApplicationInstance
    @ApplicationScope
    @Provides
    fun provideApplication() : Application = app
}
```

***FirebaseAuthModule.kt***

```
@Module
class FirebaseAuthModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    public fun getFirebaseAuth() : FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
}
```

***NetworkModule.kt***

```
@Module
class NetworkModule {

    @Provides
    @ApplicationScope
    public fun getGlideApplicationInstance(@ApplicationContext applicationContext: Context ) : Glide {
        return Glide.get(applicationContext);
    }
}
```

***FirebaseChatApp.kt*** An Application Class

```
class FirebaseChatApp : Application() {

        val firebaseComponent: FirebaseComponent by lazy {
            DaggerFirebaseComponent
                    .builder()
                    .applicationModule(ApplicationModule(this))
                    .build()
        }

    @Inject
    lateinit var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth

    @Inject
    lateinit var glide : Glide


    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        firebaseComponent.inject(this)
        Log.i("application", "APP->Firebase Auth = " + firebaseAuth)
        Log.i("application", "APP->Glide = " + glide)
    }

    public fun getApplicationComponent() : FirebaseComponent = firebaseComponent;
}
```

***BaseActivity.kt*** Super classes for all activities

```
public abstract class BaseActivity : AppCompatActivity(){
    @Inject
    @ActivityScope
    protected lateinit var glide : Glide

    @Inject
    @ApplicationScope
    protected lateinit var firebaseAuth : FirebaseAuth //ERROR HERE

    protected val activityComponent: ActivityComponent by lazy {
        DaggerActivityComponent
                .builder()
                .activityModule(ActivityModule(this))
                .firebaseComponent((this.application as FirebaseChatApp).getApplicationComponent())
                .build()
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        injectComponent(activityComponent)
    }
     abstract fun injectComponent(activityComponent: ActivityComponent)
}
```

***MainActivity.kt*** Where Objects should get Injected.

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity() {


    override fun injectComponent(activityComponent: ActivityComponent) {
        activityComponent.inject(this)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }
}
```

What should I do to resolve this error. And what is the correct way of using DI. Since I am new to it. I am getting little confused.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided \[...\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are trying to use component dependencies, but you've skipped adding the provision methods that your subscoped component can inherit.

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = arrayOf(ApplicationModule::class, FirebaseAuthModule::class, NetworkModule::class))
interface FirebaseComponent {
    fun firebaseAuth() : FirebaseAuth // <-- this is missing

    fun inject(app: FirebaseChatApp)
}
```

Comment: e: /home/arifur/source_code/me/myprojects/Learn/studio/Android/kotlin/FirebaseChat/app/build/tmp/kapt3/stubs/debug/com/example/arifur/firebasechatkotlin/dependecies/component/ActivityComponent.java:8: error: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: If I remove dependencies and add modules in the module array. I am getting error related to not able to mix scopes

Comment: Are you getting the `FirebaseAuth cannot be provided` error even **after** adding the method I specified in the answer?

Comment: Sorry. My mistake. I have put it in activity component. Thank you :)