# Dagger 2 For Android "cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"

Tags: android, dagger-2, android-mvp, dagger

I'm trying to use the latest version of Dagger 2 V2.11 for Android
Here is my code:
`AppComponent`:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityBuildersModule.class,
        FragmentBuildersModule.class
})
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MyApplication myApplication);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();
    }

    @ExceptionRequestsQualifier
    ExceptionRequestsServices exceptionRequestsServices();

}
```

`AppModule`:

```
@Module(includes = {ActivityModule.class, FragmentModule.class})
public class AppModule {

    @Provides
    CompositeDisposable provideCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    @Provides
    @ExceptionRequestsQualifier
    ExceptionRequestsServices provideExceptionRequests() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .baseUrl(APIConstants.EXCEPTION_REQUESTS_BASE_URL)
                .build()
                .create(ExceptionRequestsServices.class);
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    NetworkManager provideNetworkManager(Application app) {
        return new NetworkManager(app);
    }

}
```

`ActivityBuildersModule`:

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBuildersModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ExceptionRequestsActivity contributeExceptionRequestsActivity();

}
```

`ActivityModule`:

```
@Module()
public abstract class ActivityModule {

    @Provides
    @ActivityScope
    static ExceptionRequestsMvpPresenter<ExceptionRequestsMvpView> bindExceptionRequestsPresenter(
            ExceptionRequestsPresenter<ExceptionRequestsMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

`FragmentBuildersModule`:

```
@Module
public abstract class FragmentBuildersModule {

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract AddApplicantFragment contributeAddApplicantFragment();

    @FragmentScope
    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract PledgeFragment contributePledgeFragment();

}
```

`FragmentModule`:

```
@Module()
public abstract class FragmentModule {

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    static AddApplicantMvpPresenter<AddApplicantMvpView> bindAddApplicantPresenter(
            AddApplicantPresenter<AddApplicantMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

    @Provides
    @FragmentScope
    static PledgeMvpPresenter<PledgeMvpView> bindPledgePresenter(
            PledgePresenter<PledgeMvpView> presenter) {
        return presenter;
    }

}
```

`AddApplicantPresenter`:

```
public class AddApplicantPresenter<V extends AddApplicantMvpView> extends BasePresenter<V> implements AddApplicantMvpPresenter<V> {

    @Inject
    @ExceptionRequestsQualifier
    ExceptionRequestsServices mExceptionRequestsServices;

    @Inject
    NetworkManager mNetworkManager;

    @Inject
    public AddApplicantPresenter(CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        super(compositeDisposable);
    }

}
```

`AddApplicantMvpPresenter`:

```
@FragmentScope
public interface AddApplicantMvpPresenter<V extends AddApplicantMvpView> extends MvpPresenter<V> {

    void addApplicant(String name, String qatarId,
                      String date, String mobile,
                      ChosenImage chosenImage);

}
```

`ActivityScope`:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityScope {
}
```

`FragmentScope`:

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface FragmentScope {
}
```

`Error Log`:

```
Error:(21, 1) error: mypackagename.di.component.AppComponent scoped with @Singleton may not reference bindings with different scopes:
@Provides @mypackagename.di.scope.ActivityScope mypackagename.ui.exceptionrequests.ExceptionRequestsMvpPresenter<mypackagename.ui.exceptionrequests.ExceptionRequestsMvpView> mypackagename.di.module.ActivityModule.bindExceptionRequestsPresenter(mypackagename.ui.exceptionrequests.ExceptionRequestsPresenter<mypackagename.ui.exceptionrequests.ExceptionRequestsMvpView>)
@Provides @mypackagename.di.scope.FragmentScope mypackagename.ui.addapplicant.AddApplicantMvpPresenter<mypackagename.ui.addapplicant.AddApplicantMvpView> mypackagename.di.module.FragmentModule.bindAddApplicantPresenter(mypackagename.ui.addapplicant.AddApplicantPresenter<mypackagename.ui.addapplicant.AddApplicantMvpView>)
@Provides @mypackagename.di.scope.FragmentScope mypackagename.ui.pledge.PledgeMvpPresenter<mypackagename.ui.pledge.PledgeMvpView> mypackagename.di.module.FragmentModule.bindPledgePresenter(mypackagename.ui.pledge.PledgePresenter<mypackagename.ui.pledge.PledgeMvpView>)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided \[...\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided)

Comment: You only provide `@ExceptionRequestsQualifier ExceptionRequestsServices` but your component tries to expose `ExceptionRequestsServices`, which it doesn't know about.

Comment: @DavidMedenjak I added `@ExceptionRequestsQualifier` to `ExceptionRequestsServices` and i updated my question and error log.

Comment: You can't provide things `@ActivityScope`'d from a `@Singleton` component. See your submodules on `AppModule`

Comment: So how i can do that exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Modules` & `Components` can't have different `Scopes`
You can have `Components` to have multiple `Scopes` and this can solve it.
Try to move it to different component and add it as component dependencies

I hope in future they can solve this, the way I've done it in my project.
Currently, Dagger2 allows module with NoScope & single scope. This should match with your components.

Thumb Rule:: Different scopes have different components.
For your application, you need three components, 
`FragmentComponent` (`FragmentScope`)   :- (Ideally this should be `ActivityComponent`)
`ApplicationComponent` (`Singleton`)

https://medium.com/@patrykpoborca/making-a-best-practice-app-4-dagger-2-267ec5f6c89a
Read more about scopes.