# dagger 2 not generating component class

Tags: android, dagger-2, dagger

I tried to use dagger 2 for the first time in one of my apps. Im getting error at dagger component class as the class did not get generated. please help me to get it work.

Link to my app https://github.com/kantigaricharan/Zolo

This the Error

```
    02:45:55.663 [ERROR] [system.err] /Users/vamsikrishna/Downloads/Zolo/app/src/main/java/com/example/saicharan/zolo/dagger/component/AppComponent.java:17: error: com.example.saicharan.zolo.dashboard.DashboardInteractorImpl cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
02:45:55.663 [ERROR] [system.err]     void inject(MyApp myApp);
02:45:55.663 [ERROR] [system.err]          ^
02:45:55.663 [ERROR] [system.err]       com.example.saicharan.zolo.dashboard.DashboardInteractorImpl is injected at
02:45:55.663 [ERROR] [system.err]           com.example.saicharan.zolo.MyApp.dashboardInteractor
02:45:55.664 [ERROR] [system.err]       com.example.saicharan.zolo.MyApp is injected at
02:45:55.664 [ERROR] [system.err]           com.example.saicharan.zolo.dagger.component.AppComponent.inject(myApp)
02:45:55.722 [ERROR] [system.err] 1 error
```

This is my Component class in dagger

```
   @Singleton @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MyApp myApp);
    void inject(DashboardInteractorImpl dashboardInteractorImpl);
}
```

This is module

```
    @Module
public class AppModule {
    private final MyApp myApp;
    public AppModule(MyApp myApp){this.myApp=myApp;}

    @Provides @Singleton
    Context providesApplicationContext(){
        return myApp;
    }
    @Provides @Singleton
    SessionManagement getSession(Context context){
        return  new SessionManagement(myApp);
    }
    @Provides @Singleton
    DatabaseHelper getDhelper(Context context){
        return new DatabaseHelper(myApp);
    }
}
```

Application class

```
    public class MyApp extends Application {

    protected AppComponent appComponent;
    private static MyApp instance;
    @Inject
    DashboardInteractorImpl dashboardInteractor;

    public static MyApp getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
       // return (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext();
          return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
        appComponent.inject(this);
    }
    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){
        return appComponent;
    }
}
```

DasboardInteractorImpl

```
   public class DashboardInteractorImpl implements DashboardInteractor {

    private final DatabaseHelper dHelper;
    private final SessionManagement sManager;
    DashboardPresenterImpl mDashboardPresenter;

    public DashboardInteractorImpl(DashboardPresenterImpl mDashboardPresenter){
        this.mDashboardPresenter=mDashboardPresenter;

        dHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MyApp.getContext());
        sManager= new SessionManagement(MyApp.getContext());
    }
     //SOME LOGIC HERE..
}
```

Can i know what went wrong with my app?

Comment: Did you rebuild your project after creating modules and components?

Comment: get rid of apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt' - all of your `apt` should be replaced by `annotationProcessor` if possible

Comment: @eurosecom Yeah i have done that but still didn't resolve the error

Comment: @DavidRawson Its now giving Gradle dsl method not found apt, when i tried to sync the gradle

Comment: You still have `apt` for ButterKnife 
`apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.0'` - check the ButterKnife page for the correct lines to put in the gradle

Comment: https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife look what it says there in the canonical source and check your project is doing the same thing :-)

Comment: @DavidRawson Now im getting this error DashboardInteractorImpl cannot be provided without an Inject constructor or from an Provides- or Produces-annotated method

Comment: okay - that means Dagger 2 is working now! you just need to make sure you have set up your object graph correctly.

Comment: @DavidRawson Im updating my ques.Just check it once

Comment: See this question for how to solve that problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided

Comment: @DavidRawson i have updated my ques

Comment: you need to include the code for `DashboardInteractorImpl`

Comment: @DavidRawson included

Comment: @charanreddy please check the answer see if it solves your problem.

Comment: @HimeshGoswami i have included my github link

Answer (score 2):

When you want Dagger 2 to provide a class for you, make sure you annotate the constructor with an `@Inject` annotation:

```
@Inject
public DashboardInteractorImpl(DashboardPresenterImpl mDashboardPresenter){
    this.mDashboardPresenter=mDashboardPresenter;

    dHelper = new DatabaseHelper(MyApp.getContext());
    sManager= new SessionManagement(MyApp.getContext());
}
```

Also, get rid of the line for injecting in your app:

```
@Singleton @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
   void inject(MyApp myApp);

   //delete the line below:
   //void inject(DashboardInteractorImpl dashboardInteractorImpl);
}
```

You will also need to make sure that Dagger 2 can provide `DashboardPresenterImpl` either by annotating the constructor for the presenter with `@Inject` or by writing a `@Provides` method inside a module.

Comment: i added @Inject to both presenter and interactor, its now giving error

Comment: DashboardView cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Dashboard view is just an interface

Comment: let me do one thing i will update my code on github, so that u can view my whole code there.

Comment: Are you There??

Comment: @charan reddy i have a meeting now sorry - put the code on github and i will look later

Comment: @charan Please carefully read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided?noredirect=1&lq=1 in the meantime, I think if you read carefully you will be able to solve the issue yourself

Comment: @charanreddy i checked your Github project. You haven't written any modules besides the AppModule! You need to write modules for your dashboard etc. See the Google sample project todo-mvp-dagger [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture)

Comment: Yes, i tried to understand it, but im not getting how to instantiate my presenter and interactor class. Can you help me in doing that?  I would lilke to know what should i do to remove the hard dependencies from my app.. please do bear me as im implementing dagger for the first time

Answer (score 0):

Try using following modification

```java
// Component
@Singleton @Component(modules = AppModule.class)
public interface AppComponent {
    void inject(MyApp myApp);

    DashboardInteractorImpl getDashboardInteractorImpl();
}

// Module
@Module 
public class AppModule { 
    private final MyApp myApp;
    public AppModule(MyApp myApp){this.myApp=myApp;}

    @Provides @Singleton 
    Context providesApplicationContext(){
        return myApp;
    } 
    @Provides @Singleton 
    SessionManagement getSession(Context context){
        return  new SessionManagement(context);
    } 
    @Provides @Singleton 
    DatabaseHelper getDhelper(Context context){
        return new DatabaseHelper(context);
    } 
}

// Application
public class MyApp extends Application {

    protected AppComponent appComponent;
    private static MyApp instance;
    @Inject 
    DashboardInteractorImpl dashboardInteractor;

    public static MyApp getInstance() { 
        return instance;
    } 

    public static Context getContext(){
       // return (MyApp) context.getApplicationContext(); 
          return instance.getApplicationContext();
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onCreate() { 
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate(); 
        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent
                .builder() 
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build(); 
        appComponent.inject(this);
    } 
    public AppComponent getAppComponent(){ 
        return appComponent;
    } 
} 

// DashboardInteractorImpl
public class DashboardInteractorImpl implements DashboardInteractor {

    private final DatabaseHelper dHelper;
    private final SessionManagement sManager;
    private DashboardPresenterImpl mDashboardPresenter;

    @Inject 
    public DashboardInteractorImpl(DatabaseHelper databaseHelper,
                SessionManagement sessionManagement
                DashboardPresenterImpl dashboardPresenter){

        dHelper = databaseHelper;
        sManager = sessionManagement;
        mDashboardPresenter = dashboardPresenter;
    }
     //SOME LOGIC HERE..
}

// DashboardPresenterImpl
public class DashboardPresenterImpl implements DashboardPresenter {

    @Inject     
    public DashboardPresenterImpl(ABC abc){
        //make sure ABC is provided by the module or inject on constructed
    }
}
```

Comment: i will share my project on github.. can you please have a look on it. And correct me please??.. its very important for me to understand the dagger 2 and im failing to understand it completely.

Comment: @charanreddy Have you read all the 3 of My articles on Dagger 2: https://blog.mindorks.com/introduction-to-dagger-2-using-dependency-injection-in-android-part-2-b55857911bcd

Answer (score 0):

You can inject `DashboardInteractorImpl` with two ways.

Either you have to Declare `DashboardInteractorImpl` Dependency in App module.

Or

You can write `@Inject` constructor. 
I did not see any code that full fill this Dependency. 
so you can do two thing you can 
Provide this `DashboardPresenterImpl, DashboardInteractorImpl` in module 
or
Create `@Inject` constructor for each of this class `DashboardPresenterImpl`, `DashboardInteractorImpl`.

Comment: After using @Inject on Constructors of both presenter and interactor.. Im getting circular dependency error

Comment: Can you please download the code on your desktop and try it on your android studio.. its very important for me to understand how to implement dagger on my app.

Comment: did you presenter depends on DashboardInteractorImpl ? circular dependency means both are relay on each other.

Comment: please go through the code once.. so that you can understand the clear picture of what im trying to do and correct me

Comment: I did not find any construction injection or module that have DashboardInteractorImpl.

Answer (score -1):

If you use or write code in Kotlin add this line code inside build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```