# MVVM Dagger2 A Binding With Matching Key Exists in Component

Tags: android, mvvm, dagger-2, android-architecture-components, android-mvvm

I am using the following google sample project: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components as a reference for my new project and having difficulties trying to add a second activity to the project.

Here is the error I get when compiling

```
Error:(22, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] com.apps.myapp.ui.common.MainActivity cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method. This type supports members injection but cannot be implicitly provided.
com.apps.myapp.ui.common.MainActivity is injected at
com.apps.myapp.ui.common.NavigationController.<init>(mainActivity)
com.apps.myapp.ui.common.NavigationController is injected at
com.apps.myapp.ui.addContacts.AddContactsFragment.navigationController
com.apps.myapp.ui.addContacts.AddContactsFragment is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
A binding with matching key exists in component: com.apps.myapp.di.ActivityModule_ContributeMainActivity.MainActivitySubcomponent
```

Here is my code

ActivityModule

```java
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)
    abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = FragmentBuildersModule.class)
    abstract ContactActivity contributeContactActivity();
}
```

AppComponent

```java
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class,
        AppModule.class,
        ActivityModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance Builder application(Application application);
        AppComponent build();
    }
    void inject(App app);
}
```

AppInjector

```java
public class AppInjector {
    private AppInjector() {}
    public static void init(App app) {DaggerAppComponent.builder().application(app).build().inject(app);
                    app.registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
                    @Override
                    public void onActivityCreated(Activity activity, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                        handleActivity(activity);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityStarted(Activity activity) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityResumed(Activity activity) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityPaused(Activity activity) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityStopped(Activity activity) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(Activity activity, Bundle outState) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onActivityDestroyed(Activity activity) {

                    }
                });
    }

    private static void handleActivity(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceof HasSupportFragmentInjector) {
            AndroidInjection.inject(activity);
        }
        if (activity instanceof FragmentActivity) {
            ((FragmentActivity) activity).getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .registerFragmentLifecycleCallbacks(
                            new FragmentManager.FragmentLifecycleCallbacks() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFragmentCreated(FragmentManager fm, Fragment f,
                                        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                                    if (f instanceof Injectable) {
                                        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(f);
                                    }
                                }
                            }, true);
        }
    }
}
```

AppModule

```java
@Module(includes = ViewModelModule.class)
class AppModule {
    @Singleton @Provides
    BnderAPIService provideService() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("serverurl")
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(new LiveDataCallAdapterFactory())
                .build()
                .create(APIService.class);
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    Db provideDb(Application app) {
        return Room.databaseBuilder(app, Db.class,"Db.db").build();
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    UserDao provideUserDao(Db db) {
        return db.userDao();
    }

    @Singleton @Provides
    ContactDao provideContactDao(Db db) {
        return db.contactDao();
    }
}
```

FragmentBuildersModule

```java
@Module
public abstract class FragmentBuildersModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract AddContactsFragment contributeAddUserFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ContactsFragment contributeContactsFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract ChalkboardFragment contributeChalkboardFragment();
}
```

Injectable

```java
public interface Injectable {
}
```

ViewModelKey

```java
@Documented
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@MapKey
@interface ViewModelKey {
    Class<? extends ViewModel> value();
}
```

ViewModelModule

```java
@Module
abstract class ViewModelModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(AddContactsViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindAddContactsViewModel(AddContactsViewModel addContactsViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ContactsViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindContactsViewModel(ContactsViewModel contactsViewModel);

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(ChalkboardViewModel.class)
    abstract ViewModel bindChalkboardViewModel(ChalkboardViewModel chalkboardViewModel);

    @Binds
    abstract ViewModelProvider.Factory bindViewModelFactory(ViewModelFactory factory);
}
```

Application

```java
public class App extends Application implements HasActivityInjector {

    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {

        }
        AppInjector.init(this);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Activity> activityInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

NavigationController

```java
public class NavigationController {
    private final int containerId;
    private final FragmentManager fragmentManager;
    @Inject
    public NavigationController(MainActivity mainActivity) {
        this.containerId = R.id.container;
        this.fragmentManager = mainActivity.getSupportFragmentManager();
    }

    public void navigateToUsers() {
        Log.i("TAG", "Navigate to users");
        String tag = "users";
        AddContactsFragment userFragment = AddContactsFragment.create();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(containerId, userFragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    public void navigateToContacts() {
        Log.i("TAG", "Navigate to contacts");
        String tag = "contacts";
        ContactsFragment contactsFragment = ContactsFragment.create();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(contactsFragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    public void navigateToChalkboard() {
        Log.i("TAG", "Navigate to chalkboard");
        String tag = "chalkboard";
        ChalkboardFragment chalkboardFragment = ChalkboardFragment.create();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(chalkboardFragment, tag)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleRegistryOwner, HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    private final LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    @Inject
    NavigationController navigationController;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycleRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
        binding.setHandler(this);
        binding.setManager(getSupportFragmentManager());
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }

    static class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
        }
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"handler"})
    public static void bindViewPagerAdapter(final ViewPager view, final MainActivity activity) {
        final ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(activity.getSupportFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new ChalkboardFragment(), "Chalkboard");
        adapter.addFragment(new ContactsFragment(), "Contacts");
        view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"pager"})
    public static void bindViewPagerTabs(final TabLayout view, final ViewPager pagerView) {
        view.setupWithViewPager(pagerView, true);
    }
}
```

ContactActivity

```java
public class ContactActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LifecycleRegistryOwner, HasSupportFragmentInjector {
    private final LifecycleRegistry lifecycleRegistry = new LifecycleRegistry(this);
    @Inject
    DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    @Override
    public LifecycleRegistry getLifecycle() {
        return lifecycleRegistry;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact);
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public DispatchingAndroidInjector<Fragment> supportFragmentInjector() {
        return dispatchingAndroidInjector;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `NavigationController` depends on `MainActivity`, which is not "known" to Dagger. You will have to add an `@Provides` annotated method to a module used by the component that returns `MainActivity` so that Dagger can provide it to your controller,  or resolve your conflict in a different fashion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided \[...\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided)

Comment: Yes the NavigationController depends on my MainActivity (I also added the code of it to my answer), however I believe it must be known to Dagger as everything worked fine prior to me trying to add another activity (ContactActivity)..only then did I end up getting these errors.

Comment: If you have a look at the linked Question you'll see how to read the error. Your `AddContactsFragment` does not have access to the `MainActivity`, I'm guessing it's part of a sub graph of `AddContactsActivity`, and has no knowledge of `MainActivity`

Comment: I am confused to be honest - before adding ContactActivity and the extra    @ContributesAndroidInjector line in the ActivityModule, everything compiled fine...So I am not sure how adding those bits of code could cause those fragments to no longer have access to the MainActivity...maybe I am missing something

Comment: Have a look at Components and specifically subcomponents. AppComponent parent of MainActivitySubComponent parent of MainFragmentSubcomponent, or something. The same for ContatctActivity which is parent of ContactFragment. The problem is Contact Fragment now only sees ContactActivity, not MainActivity, since MainActivity with its component is not its parent, hence the injection fails

Answer (score 22, accepted):

"A binding with matching key exists in component" means that you have bound a dependency somewhere in your entire object graph but it cannot be reached from the subcomponent where it needs to be injected. Here is the javadoc:

> Utility code that looks for bindings matching a key in all subcomponents in a binding graph so that a user is advised that a binding exists elsewhere when it is not found in the current subgraph. If a binding matching a key exists in a sub- or sibling component, that is often what the user actually wants to use.

[image: A diagram of where the binding is present in the sibling component]

For instance, assume you have two Activities, ActivityA and ActivityB. You generate subcomponents with `@ContributesAndroidInjector` and bind `Foo` in the ActivityA module but not the ActivityB module. If you request injection for `Foo` in ActivityB with `@Inject Foo foo` you will get that error message.

In your particular case, the error you are getting can be reproduced by:

1. Cloning the project from GitHub

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components.git`
   ```
2. Copy-pasting `MainActivity` into a new file `ContactsActivity`
3. Modifying `MainActivityModule` to look like your `ActivityModule`

So from this we can conclude that your `ActivityModule` is problematic. The `@ContributesAndroidInjector` is not as simple as it might seem. It actually means you are creating a new Dagger 2 subcomponent for the Activity you specify there (see the [docs here](https://google.github.io/dagger//android.html)).

A subcomponent can use bindings from a parent component but not sibling components. Your two lines for `ContributesAndroidInjector` in the `ActivityModule` create two sibling subcomponents: one for `MainActivity` and one for `ContactsActivity`.

However, `NavigationController` is dependent on `MainActivity` which is bound in the object graph for the `MainActivity` subcomponent but not in that for the `ContactsActivity` subcomponent. `AddContactsFragment` has become part of the object graph for the `ContactsActivity` subcomponent and doesn't have access to `MainActivity` anymore. This means that when Dagger 2 tries to inject the `NavigationController` inside your `AddContactsFragment` it cannot provide `MainActivity` as a dependency for it. This explains the "cannot provide" part of the error message.

Although it can't provide `MainActivity` in that particular object graph, the `AndroidInjector` *does* know in general about `MainActivity` hence the error message "a binding key exists". What binding key is this? A key that binds `MainActivity.class` to a `MainActivityFactory`. Where is this key bound? In your `ActivityModule` when you wrote the `@ContributesAndroidInjector` for `MainActivity`.

How to fix this is getting beyond scope of a StackOverflow question because it involves a lengthy refactor of the code. You would need to re-organise the object graph so that the `NavigationController` no longer depends on `MainActivity`. Perhaps you could make it depend on `AppCompatActivity` since that is a superclass of both your Activities. You would then need to stop using `ContributesAndroidInjector` and write explicit modules for your two Activities that include bindings for `AppCompatActivity`.

However, for now please go back to basics and start with something easier. It is a recipe for disaster to start with a complex project without a complete understanding and just modify it hoping that it will work.

The [Codepath Dagger 2 tutorial project](https://github.com/codepath/dagger2-example) is much easier to understand and will get you familiar with the basic concepts involved in Dagger 2. Once you are comfortable with the basic concepts and have understood dependent components and sub-components, then you can attempt a more difficult example. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! As suggested I will take some time looking into Dagger 2 to fully understand it before starting with such an advanced sample

Comment: @RileyMacDonald you're welcome. I forgot to mention also that the advanced example is not really suited for a multiple-activity app. It is set up for one single Activity and multiple Fragments so it's going to be quite difficult to adapt to something else. You can also have a look at https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture where there is a sample "todo" app with multiple activities wired up using Dagger 2.