# Context cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method in kotlin

Tags: android, dependency-injection, kotlin, dagger-2

I am using Dagger for dependency injection in Kotlin. Now here are the necessary classes

**ActivityModule**

```
@Module class ActivityModule (val activity : Activity){
    @Provides
    @ActivityContext
    fun provideContext() : Context{
        return activity
    }
}
```

**ActivityComponent**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = arrayOf(ApplicationComponent::class), modules = arrayOf(ActivityModule::class))
interface ActivityComponent {
    fun inject(activity: MainActivity)
}
```

**MainActivity**

```
@Inject @ActivityContext lateinit var context:Context
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        DaggerActivityComponent.builder()
.applicationComponent(MainApplication.getInstance().getApplicationComponent()).activityModule(ActivityModule(this)).build()
.inject(this);
```

Now I am getting the following error

```
error: android.content.Context cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
e: 

e:     public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
e:                          ^
e:       android.content.Context is injected at
e:           app.feed.com.ui.MainActivity.context
e:       app.feed.com.ui.MainActivity is injected at
e:           app.feed.com.injection.component.ActivityComponent.inject(p0)
```

**I am using the same code in java and its working fine** but here in kotlin its giving the error, also `ApplicaionComponent` dependencies are working fine. Meanwhile i am using the following versions of gradle and kotlin

```
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.1.2-3'
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Kindly help me to figure out what am I doing wrong

Comment: show dependencies too, especially dagger

Comment: `compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.12'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.12'
    kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.12'`

Comment: What's the point of this injection, you're providing itself?

Comment: In actual scenario the injection happens in some fragment

Comment: You're using a qualifier `@ActivityContext`. Either remove it in your module so that you provide a plain `Context`, or also add it in your MainActivity so that you request a `@ActivityContext Context`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '... cannot be provided \[...\]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44912080/how-do-i-fix-dagger-2-error-cannot-be-provided)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak, I see he has declared `@Inject @ActivityContext lateinit var context:Context` in activity.

Comment: @azizbekian Thank you, I overlooked that. @Debu I still believe this is a problem with the qualifier, please include the source of the `@ActivityContext` annotation and try if it would work without it

Comment: its working if I remove `@ActivityContext` , now what if I want to provide separate context for activity and application??

Comment: @Debu as I said, please include the code of the annotation so that we can verify it

Comment: `@Qualifier
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface ActivityContext {
}  `

Comment: @Debu You should try switching to a Kotlin annotation

Answer (score 5):

You injected property

```
@Inject @ActivityContext lateinit var context: Context
```

only annotates the property with `@ActivityContext`. So *Dagger* is looking for a provider for a simple `Context` without any qualifier. Instead you have to annotate the field with it

```
@Inject @field:ActivityContext lateinit var context: Context
```