# retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, dagger-2

I create `dagger2` `Conponent` and `Subcomponent`

Main Component:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {PresentersModule.class, RepositoriesModule.class, UtilsModule.class, AppModule.class, RoomModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {

    SettingsComponent plusSettingsComponent(NetworkModule networkModule);
...
```

My subcomponent:

```
@Upgradable
@Subcomponent(modules = {NetworkModule.class})
public interface SettingsComponent {
    RestApiFactory getRestApiFactory();
}
```

I want set `RestApiFactory`  from `subcomponent` like parameter in `main component`

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    TransactionsRepository provideTransactionsRepository(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
        return new TransactionsRepositoryImpl(restApiFactory);
    }
```

but `RestApiFactory` contains in `Subcomponent`

Now I make this- in Application class I have method:

```
public SettingsComponent plusSettingsComponent() {
        if (settingsComponent == null) {
            settingsComponent = appComponent.plusSettingsComponent(new NetworkModule());
        }
        return settingsComponent;
    }
```

And call it in repository:

```
return MyApplication.me().plusSettingsComponent().getRestApiFactory()
                .getTransactionsService()
                .getTransactions(transactionRequest, page);
```

if I try set `RestApiFactory` like parameter - I get error:

I cahge method to this:

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    TransactionsRepository provideTransactionsRepository(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
        return new TransactionsRepositoryImpl(restApiFactory);
    }
```

And change this:

```
private RestApiFactory restApiFactory;

    @Inject
    public TransactionsRepositoryImpl(RestApiFactory restApiFactory) {
        this.restApiFactory = restApiFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public Observable<List<TransactionItem>> loadTransactions(TransactionRequest transactionRequest, int page) {
        return restApiFactory.getTransactionsService()
                .getTransactions(transactionRequest, page);
    }
```

Error

```
Error:(30, 27) error: retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
```

full error

```
Error:(30, 27) error: retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
my.network.api.RestApiFactory.<init>(retrofit)
my.network.api.RestApiFactory is injected at
my.dagger.RepositoriesModule.provideTransactionsRepository(restApiFactory)
my.repositories.TransactionsRepository is injected at
my.dagger.PresentersModule.provideTransactionsPresenter(…, transactionsRepository)
my.presenters.TransactionsPresenter is provided at
my.dagger.AppComponent.getTransactionsPresenter()
A binding with matching key exists in component: my.dagger.SettingsComponent
```

Comment: Can you post your NetworkModule? It seems you try to inject something that you haven't declared

Comment: Please update your question to include the full error message and the related code. Your current question does not reference `Retrofit` anywhere other than the error message, but the error would indicate that you try to inject it somewhere. You can find a generic answer to your question here, as well as an example on what to include in your question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367

Comment: @ David Medenjak I added full error

Comment: I haven't used subcomponents on dagger2 and I'm a bit lost in wahat you try to do. What are you trying to inject? It's not clear. What I did to get my retrofit instance is to create a ``@Provides`` method where instantiate, create interceptors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the stacktrace of the error message:

```
Error:(30, 27) error: retrofit2.Retrofit cannot be provided without an @Inject constructor or from an @Provides-annotated method.
retrofit2.Retrofit is injected at
my.network.api.RestApiFactory.<init>(retrofit)
my.network.api.RestApiFactory is injected at
my.dagger.RepositoriesModule.provideTransactionsRepository(restApiFactory)
my.repositories.TransactionsRepository is injected at
my.dagger.PresentersModule.provideTransactionsPresenter(…, transactionsRepository)
my.presenters.TransactionsPresenter is provided at
my.dagger.AppComponent.getTransactionsPresenter()
A binding with matching key exists in component: my.dagger.SettingsComponent
```

It says you are injecting `Retrofit` at `RestApiFactory`.

`RestApiFactory` is provided in your `RepositoriesModule` when you provide `TransactionsRepository`

`TransactionsRepository`, in turn, is injected in your `PresentersModule` which you use to provide in the provision method `getPresenter` of your `AppComponent`.

So it seems you are trying to use a binding from a sub-component (`Retrofit` bound in `SettingsComponent`) in a super-component (`AppComponent`). This explains the "binding key exists in `SettingsComponent` error message - `Retrofit` is indeed bound but not in the correct way.

You can't use bindings from sub-components in super-components - dependencies bubble down rather than float upwards. Dependencies you want to use in multiple sub-components should be bound at the top-level and exposed to sub-components.