# Class did not get auto generated

Tags: java, android, dagger-2, dagger

I am learning how to use Dagger2. I created an example as shown below in the code. the issue I am facing is, the auto generated class by Daggers, the one
that should be called "DaggerInterfaceComponent" is never gets created. The below DaggerInterfaceComponent is underscored with red.

Please have a look at the build gradle App posted below.

**code**:

```
InterfaceComponent component = DaggerInterfaceComponent.builder().objectValuesModule(new ObjectValuesModule()).build();
    Object injectedObject = component.getObjectValues();

    int returnedInt = injectedObject.getreturnInteger();
    int returnedStr = injectedObject.getReturnString();
    int returnedObj = injectedObject.getReturnObject();
```

**gradle App**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-
core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

compile "com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11"
annotationProcessor "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.11"
provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
}
```

Comment: Clear and build project

Comment: Dagger generates the interface implementation as a part of compilation, and if it encounters any errors, the file is not generated. Thank you for posting your Gradle file and the instantiation, but please also post the source code to your _component interface_, _relevant modules_, and (most important) any _compiler errors_ like the one at the top of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48380865/1426891) ("HomePresenter cannot be provided...").