# Dagger2 inject a list of childFragments in a parentFragment cause Error: cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: android, android-fragments, dagger-2, dagger

I have a `MainActivity`, and There is a nested `MainFragment` in my `MainActivity`, and even more, There are a list of `ChildFragment` in the `MainFragment`.Every `Activity` or `Fragment` has a `Module` and `Subcomponent`. Now I want to inject the list of `ChildFragment` int the `MainFragment`, but If I use the `List<Fragment>` provided method with the `@FragmentScoped` annotation in the `MainFragmentModule`, it will cause an error which said the fragment list cannot be provided without an `@Provides-annotated` method. Instead if I put the `List<Fragment>` provided method in the `MainActivityModule` with annotation `@ActivityScoped`, it works.Could anyone tell me that's why?
Here is the code:

MainActivityModule :

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {
    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainFragmentModule.class})
    @FragmentScoped
    abstract MainFragment mainFragment();
}
```

MainFragmentModule :

```
@Module
public abstract class MainFragmentModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {HomeModule.class})
    @ChildFragmentScoped
    abstract HomeFragment homeFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ChildFragmentScoped
    abstract NewsFragment newsFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ChildFragmentScoped
    abstract MomentsFragment momentsFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ChildFragmentScoped
    abstract WalletFragment walletFragment();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    @ChildFragmentScoped
    abstract PersonalFragment personalFragment();

    @FragmentScoped
    @Provides
    static List<Fragment> provideList(HomeFragment home, NewsFragment news, MomentsFragment moments, WalletFragment wallet, PersonalFragment personal) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(home);
        fragments.add(news);
        fragments.add(moments);
        fragments.add(wallet);
        fragments.add(personal);
        return fragments;
    }
}
```

FragmentAdapter:

```
public class FragmentAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    //...

    @Inject
    public FragmentAdapter(List<Fragment> fragments, FragmentUtil fragmentUtil) {
        mFragments = fragments;
        mFragmentUtil = fragmentUtil;
    }

    //...

}
```

MainFragment:

```
public class MainFragment extends DaggerFragment{

    //...

    @Inject
    FragmentAdapter mFragmentAdapter;

    @Inject
    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    //...
}
```

If I use the `List<Fragment>` provided method with the `@FragmentScoped` annotation in the `MainFragmentModule`, it will cause the following error:

```
Error:(20, 8) Error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)]  java.util.List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
java.util.List<android.support.v4.app.Fragment> is injected at
com.sample.fragment.FragmentAdapter.<init>(fragments, …)
com.sample.fragment.FragmentAdapter is injected at
com.sample.fragment.MainFragment.mFragmentAdapter
com.sample.fragment.MainFragment is injected at
com.sample.activity.MainActivity.mMainFragment
com.sample.activity.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

But with the following code it works:

```
@Module
public abstract class MainActivityModule {

    @ActivityScoped
    @Provides
    static List<Fragment> provideList(HomeFragment home, NewsFragment news, MomentsFragment moments, WalletFragment wallet, PersonalFragment personal) {
        List<Fragment> fragments = new ArrayList<>();
        fragments.add(home);
        fragments.add(news);
        fragments.add(moments);
        fragments.add(wallet);
        fragments.add(personal);
        return fragments;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include the full error in your question. Also, please see and read here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367

Answer (score 0):

Well, It seems that I have found the problem. When I inject the `MainFragment` in my `MainActivity`, because the `MainFragment` has an `@Inject` member which is `FragmentAdapter`, it needs to inject the `FragmentAdapter` . By the same way, it needs List injected. However, I provide the List in the `MainFragmentModule`, the parent subcomponent cannot use the provided dependencies of its child subcomponent.