# How to provide retrofit interface to abstract module dagger2

Tags: android, retrofit2, dagger-2, rx-android, dagger

I'm following the new Dagger2 support for android to implement a movies list sample application and below is my use case.

- Activity Holds a fragment used to load list of movies
- Fragment uses a presenter to hit an api using retrofit
- Presenter has a dependency to the API interface class which contains Observale for the movies

I'm using @Inject inside the presenter for the ApiService interface but i got an error that i cannot use @Inject field without declaring provide annotation and below is my code

Main App component 
[image]

My Movies module 
[image]

My Movies Contract
[image]

My Presenter
[image]

and finally the api service interface

[image]

So how can i provide the service interface to MoviesModule in order to work properly inside the presenter

The error is

```
Error:(22, 8) error: [dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(T)] sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.data.MoviesApiService cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.data.MoviesApiService is injected at
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviePresenter.mApiService
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviePresenter is injected at
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviesModule.moviesPresenter(presenter)
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviesContract.Presenter is injected at
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviesFragment.mPresenter
dagger.Lazy<sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MoviesFragment> is injected at
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MainActivity.mMoviesFragmentsProvider
sampler.dagger.com.movieslist.movies.MainActivity is injected at
dagger.android.AndroidInjector.inject(arg0)
```

Comment: Please include the _code_ and not screenshots of it as well as the full error message. Please have a look here on [how to fix _cannot be provided_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367)

Comment: @DavidMedenjak just added the full error

Comment: Please have a look at the linked question as it includes all the details about your error and possible solutions. You will have to add `MoviesApiService` to one of your modules and provide it.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
@Module
public class APIModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit(Gson gson) {
        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("https://stackoverflow.com/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        return new GsonBuilder().create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    MoviesApiService provideMoviesApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
        return retrofit.create(MoviesApiService.class);
    }
}
```

In your `MoviePresenter` its better to use constructor injection than field injection:

```
private MoviesApiService mApiService;

@Inject
public MoviePresenter(MoviesApiService apiService) {
    mApiService = apiService;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

MoviApiService is an interface, you cannot inject an interface. You need to create a `provides` method to provide the retrofit service.

> MoviApiService providesMoviApiService(Retrofit retrofit) {
>   retrofit.create(MoviApiService.class);
>    }

Comment: Yes you can `@Binds`? i.e. in a Module :  `@Binds static MovieApiService provideMyApi(Retrofit retrofit) { return retrofit.create(MoviApiService.class); };`. Although OP should be using constructor injection.

Comment: That was my point, you are creating the retrofit service, not injecting a "plain interface"

Comment: @MarkKeen Binds needs the method to be abstract

Comment: '@binds' needs to be abstract, '@provides' doesn't need it

Comment: @user101530 thanks for the correction `@Provides static MovieApiService provideMyApi(Retrofit retrofit) { return retrofit.create(MoviApiService.class); };` At cherif - you can still inject an interface? The return type is fine? Your answer is still fundamentally incorrect.