# Java & AWS & Dependency Injection (DI) - cannot find symbol DaggerAppComponent

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, dependency-injection, amazon-dynamodb, dagger-2

I want to implement DI in my application, but after I did this I have issues with CRUD methods.

I've created interface:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, DbModule.class, AuthGatewayModule.class})
public interface AppComponent {
Context getContext();
GymService getGymService();
KitchenService getKitchenService();
ActivitiesService getActivitiesService();
AuthGateway getAuthGateway();
LandingService getLandingService();
Logger getLogger();

void inject(Logger logger);
}
```

This is appModule:

```
@Module
public class AppModule {
private final Context context;


public AppModule(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Context provideContext() {
    return context;
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public Logger logger() {
    return new Logger(context);
}
}
```

And dbModule:

```
@Module
public class DbModule {
@Provides
public DbService provideDbService(Logger logger) {
    return new DatabaseController(Regions.EU_CENTRAL_1, logger);
}
}
```

This is my KitchenService class with one example method:

```
public class KitchenService {

private DatabaseController databaseController;
private LambdaLogger logger;

@Inject
public KitchenService(){}

public KitchenService(DatabaseController databaseController, LambdaLogger logger) {
    this.databaseController = databaseController;
    this.logger = logger;
}

//PRODUCT CRUD METHODS
public Product addProduct(Product product) {

    databaseController.save(product);
    logger.log("Product created");

    return product;

}
```

I wanted to add some product to DB, that worked fine before I implemented DI, but now I have java.lang.NullPointerException.

And this is AddProductLambda class:

```
public class AddProductLambda extends Lambda {
@Override
public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
    super.handleRequest(input, context);
    try {
        Product product = RequestUtil.parseRequestBody(input, Product.class);
        KitchenService kitchenService = appComponent.getKitchenService();
        Product addedProduct = kitchenService.addProduct(product);
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_CREATED, addedProduct);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        return ResponseUtil.generateResponse(HttpStatus.SC_BAD_REQUEST, e.getMessage());

    }

}
}
```

And Lambda that AddProductLambda extends:

```
public abstract class Lambda implements RequestHandler<Map<String, Object>, ApiGatewayResponse> {
protected Logger logger;
protected AppComponent appComponent;

@Override
public ApiGatewayResponse handleRequest(Map<String, Object> input, Context context) {
    appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder().appModule(new AppModule(context)).build();

    logger = new Logger(context);

    // Inject logger
    appComponent.inject(logger);

    logger.log(input.toString());

    return null;
}
}
```

I did something wrong? Can someone help me with this problem?

Comment: Please check the logs, there usually would be another Dagger error there giving you more information if Dagger failed to generate some code

Comment: There is one more error:

error: com.amazonaws.regions.Regions cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    KitchenService getKitchenService();
                   ^        
      com.amazonaws.regions.Regions is injected at
          service.dynamodb.DatabaseController.<init>(regions, ů)
      service.dynamodb.DatabaseController is injected at
          service.kitchen.KitchenService.<init>(databaseController, ů)
      service.kitchen.KitchenService is provided at
          service.app.AppComponent.getKitchenService()

Comment: Please have a look at [How to fix cannot be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367). If you still need help afterwards please update your question to include all the relevant parts and highlight where you're stuck

Comment: Hey, I did everything with tutorial You sent to me and I didnt get any errors so I think DI is implemented fine, but now my CRUD methods stop working coretly. I added some classes to my question. Can You look at this?