# Inject interface in constructor of usecase

Tags: android, dagger-2

I have an interface:

```
interface CartonRepository {
    fun addToCart(company: Company): Completable
}
```

Now I want to use this interface in my use case:

```
class ObserveCartonItemSelectionUseCase
@Inject constructor(private val cartonRepository: CartonRepository) : ObservableUseCase<UUID, Boolean> {

}
```

and this use case is injected in other class by:

```
@Inject
protected lateinit var observeCartonSelectionUseCase: ObserveCartonItemSelectionUseCase
```

I get an error:

```
ApplicationComponent.java:13: error: CartonRepository cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
    public abstract void inject(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
```

Comment: So where do you define which `CartonRepository` to use? You need a module to bind it somewhere! Please also see [how to fix cannot be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44912081/1837367)

Answer (score 0):

The error says exactly what should be done to provide the `CartonRepository`. Add a `@Provides` annotation to your interface:

```
@Provided
interface CartonRepository {
fun addToCart(company: Company): Completable

}
```

That will tell Dagger that this interface should be injectable.

Comment: I can't do that. I use clean architecture and this interface is in domain module as a ObserveCartonItemSelectionUseCase. Domain module don't have Dagger dependency so I don't have @Provided annotation. I can't move interface to presentation module where I have dagger because domain cannot have dependency to presentation module