# Presenter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm struggling seeing why I get this error: `Presenter cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.`

I have even tried to just strip out everything and make it as simple as possible, but I still get the error. What am I doing wrong?

Component:

```
@Component(modules = [SplashScreenModule::class])
interface SplashScreenComponent {
   fun presenter() : SplashScreenContract.Presenter
}
```

Module:

```
@Module
abstract class SplashScreenModule {

   @Binds
   @SplashScreenScope
   abstract fun providesSplashScreenPresenter(presenter: SplashScreenPresenter) : SplashScreenContract.Presenter
}
```

Presenter:

```
class SplashScreenPresenter : SplashScreenContract.Presenter { ... }
```

Comment: Use a builder in the component with a BindsInstance, @BindsInstance abstract fun presenter()( presenter : StriSplashScreenContract.Presenterg ) : Builder

Comment: But this will require me to provide the presenter when building the component. Let's say the presenter has some dependencies, can I use BindInstance then?

Comment: Dagger does not know how to either create (add `@Inject` on the constructor) or find (add a `@Provides` annotated method to a module) `SplashScreenPresenter`. You probably want constructor injection here, but you need to supply the presenter _somehow_. Please also [see the more general information here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367)

Answer (score 0):

You need the @Inject annotation,

```
class SplashScreenPresenter @Inject constructor() : SplashScreenContract.Presenter { ... }
```

Comment: Did not help, But why would I need the @Inject constructor if I'm not injecting anything to the presenter?

Comment: @Inject when used in constructor also works as Provides. Tells Dagger to use that constructor to create an instance when needed.

Answer (score 0):

It was a silly mistake by me..

I annotated `SplashScreenScope` as `@Qualifier` instead of `@Scope`