# Will Dagger 2 work in a pure-Kotlin module, removed from the Android layer?

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2, clean-architecture

I am trying to implement a clean code architecture similar to what's described [here](https://proandroiddev.com/clean-architecture-data-flow-dependency-rule-615ffdd79e29). To enforce it, each layer is a separate module in Android Studio with the dependency chain thus:

> model(pure-kotlin) -> interactor(pure-kotlin) -> viewmodel(android) ->
>   view(android)

So to be clear, the `view` only knows about the `viewmodel` and the `viewmodel` only knows about the `interactor`. The view (normally the `app` module) is where the `MainActivity` lives.

I am currently working on the `interactor` in isolation and I am trying to use Dagger 2 for injection there. I have written the following code all in the `interactor` module:

```
... (Build.gradle)
implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.20'
kapt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.20'
...

abstract class ApiServiceInteractor() {
    @Inject lateinit var apiService: ApiService
    @Inject lateinit var schedulers: InteractorSchedulers
}

class Posts @Inject constructor() : ApiServiceInteractor() {
    fun fetch(): Single<List<PostSummary>> =
        apiService.getPosts()
            .subscribeOn(schedulers.io())
            .toObservable()
            .flatMapIterable { postList -> postList }
            .map { post -> PostSummary(post.id, post.title) }
            .toList()
}

@Module
open class InteractorModule {
    @Singleton @Provides 
    open fun provideApiService(): ApiService = ApiService.create()

    @Provides 
    open fun provideSchedulers(): InteractorSchedulers = InteractorSchedulers()
}

@Component
interface Component {
    fun inject(posts: Posts)
}

val dagger = DaggerComponent.create() // <--- not generated!!!
```

The code does not compile. The compiler complains that the injected `apiService` and `schedulers` in `ApiServiceInteractor` need a corresponding `@Provides`, furthermore the `DaggerComponent` implementation is not auto-generated. Now, I realise that the `Component` interface doesn't make sense here, but you need one to auto-generate `DaggerComponent` and this is just prototyping at this stage.

If I move the `Component` interface and the `DaggerComponent.create()` into the view (and have the inject signature use `MainActivity` instead of Posts) then everything compiles fine and `DaggerComponent` is created.

My worry is that when everything is finally written, Dagger will not be able to resolve the `@Provides` for `apiService` and `schedulers` because there is a degree of separation between the `view` and the `interactor` (where the `@Provides` are). The only examples I have seen that are anything similar to this have the `@Provides` in the `view` (`app`) module. If I do that, however, I will break the clean code architecture dependency rule because the `view` will then have a dependency on the `interactor`.

So will it work the way it is? Will those values get injected?

**UPDATE**

I removed the '@Component' and 'DaggerComponent' declarations from `view`, put them back in `interactor` and added '@Component(modules = [InteractorModule::class])'. The compiler no longer complains about missing provides (thanks Ivan), but the IDE still reports that DaggerComponent does not exist. Calling `DaggerComponent.create().inject(this)` in Posts init does not compile because DaggerComponent has not been generated.

So it appears that `DaggerComponent` can only be generated in the `view` module which means that the `@Component` declaration also has to be in the `view` module, along with the `modules = [InteractorModule::class]` annotation parameter. And once you do that, you have a dependency between `view` and `interactor` on `InteractorModule`, breaking the clean code architecture dependency rule.

So the main question still remains, how to get Dagger 2 to work in a pure-Kotlin module removed from the Android layer?

Comment: I'm not Dagger expert but, shouldn't your component have its Modules declared?
e.g. @Component(modules = [ContextModule::class])

Comment: Please always include the actual error message (_compiler complains that the injected apiService and schedulers in ApiServiceInteractor need a corresponding @Provides_). It sounds like you have an error with your dependencies, please read here about [How do I fix Dagger 2 error … cannot be provided](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367)