# How to fix "[Dagger/MissingBinding] : Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method"

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm integrating dagger with the `viewmodel`. when I include the `viewmodelprovider` factory in `AppComponent`, app is not getting build and its shows an error like

> "error: [Dagger/MissingBinding] java.util.Map,javax.inject.Provider> cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method". I have added my code below.

**ViewModelFactory**

```
class DaggerViewModelFactory
@Inject
constructor(private val creators: Map<Class<out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        var creator: Provider<out ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]
        if (creator == null) {
            for ((key, value) in creators) {
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)) {
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }
        }
        if (creator == null) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("unknown model class " + modelClass)
        }
        try {
            return creator.get() as T
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }

    }
}
```

then i have my **AppComponent** class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [AndroidInjectionModule::class, ViewModelFactoryModule::class, ActivityBuilder::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<FreedomApplication> {

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: DaggerApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent

    }
}
```

my **viewmodel** module bind class

```
@Module
abstract class WelcomeModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(WelcomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindWelcomeViewModel(welcomeViewModel: WelcomeViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

my fragment builder class

```
@Module
abstract class FragmentBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun injectWelcomeFragment() : WelcomeFragment

}
```

then my fragment class to include **viewmodelprovider** factory

```
class WelcomeFragment @Inject constructor(): DaggerFragment() {
    @Inject
    lateinit var providerFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = WelcomeFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: WelcomeViewModel

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.welcome_fragment, container, false)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(WelcomeViewModel::class.java)
        // TODO: Use the ViewModel
    }
}
```

and view model to integrate for the fragment

```
class WelcomeViewModel @Inject constructor() : ViewModel() {

    // TODO: Implement the ViewModel
}
```

Comment: You can check [How do I fix Dagger 2 error '… cannot be provided […]'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367) for some general information. Please also update your question to include the _full_ error message (as shown in the linked question) if you need further help. From a quick glance I can't see you adding `WelcomeModule` anywhere.

Comment: I have already included my welcome module.

Comment: But you're not _using_ it anywhere (`@Component(modules = [ can't find it here or similar ])`)

Comment: Is your error resolved?

Comment: yes @MohammedRampurawala

Comment: Can you please provide the solution of your question. That will help other developers

Answer (score -1):

Fixed the above issue, Kindly refer the below code.

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [ActivityBuilder::class, NetworkModule::class, ViewBindModule::class, AndroidSupportInjectionModule::class])
interface AppComponent : AndroidInjector<FreedomApplication> {

    override fun inject(application: FreedomApplication)

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        fun application(application: FreedomApplication): Builder

        fun build(): AppComponent
    }

}
```

```
@Module
abstract class ActivityBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentBuilder::class])
    abstract fun bindWelcomeActivity (): WelcomeActivity

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = [FragmentBuilder::class])
    abstract fun bindDashBoardActivity (): DashBoardActivity
}
```

```
@Module
abstract class ViewBindModule {
    @Binds
    abstract fun bindViewModelFactory(factory: DaggerViewModelFactory): ViewModelProvider.Factory

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(WelcomeViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindWelcomeViewModel(viewModel: WelcomeViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(LoginViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindLoginViewModel(viewModel: LoginViewModel): ViewModel

    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @ViewModelKey(DashBoardViewModel::class)
    abstract fun bindDashboardViewModel(viewModel: DashBoardViewModel): ViewModel
}
```

```
class DaggerViewModelFactory @Inject constructor(private val creators: Map<Class <out ViewModel>, @JvmSuppressWildcards Provider<ViewModel>>):ViewModelProvider.Factory {

    @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")

    override fun <T : ViewModel?> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
         var creator :Provider<ViewModel>? = creators[modelClass]

        if (creator == null)
            for ((key, value) in creators){
                if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(key)){
                    creator = value
                    break
                }
            }

        if (creator == null) throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown model class")
        try{
            return creator.get() as T
        }catch (e:Exception){
            throw RuntimeException(e)
        }
    }
}
```

```
abstract class FragmentBuilder {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindWelcomeFragment(): WelcomeFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindLoginFragment(): LoginFragment

    @ContributesAndroidInjector
    abstract fun bindDashBoardFragment(): DashBoardFragment
}
```