# Dagger 2 - Cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

Im using dagger 2 for DI and im getting the message error:

> MainFragmentContract.Presenter cannot be provided without an
>   @Provides-annotated method.

But when I move my **@Bind** provideMainFragmentPresenter method from my MainFragmentModule to my ActivityBindingModule it build successfully.

Why it works when i move to the ActivityBindingModule class?, also if i move that method to my ActivityBindingModule class i cant add a scope because i get the message :

> AppComponent scoped with scope.ApplicationScope may not reference
>   bindings with different scopes.

There is my code.

AppComponent.java

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {
        AndroidInjectionModule.class, // Important
        ApplicationModule.class,
        NetworkModule.class,
        ActivityBindingModule.class,
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

    void injectApplication(MyApplication myApplication);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder application(Application application);

        AppComponent build();

    }
}
```

ActivityBindingModel.java

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityBindingModule {

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {MainModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    abstract MainActivity mainActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = {LoginModule.class})
    @ActivityScope
    abstract LoginActivity loginActivity();

    @ContributesAndroidInjector(modules = MainFragmentModule.class)
    @FragmentScope
    abstract MainFragment provideMainFragment();

}
```

MainModule.java ( activity )

```
@Module
public abstract class MainModule {

    @Binds
    @ActivityScope
    public abstract MainContract.Presenter
    provideMainActivityPresenter(MainActivityPresenterImpl presenter);

}
```

MainFragmentModule.java

```
@Module
public abstract class MainFragmentModule {

    @Binds
    public abstract MainFragmentContract.Presenter
    provideMainFragmentPresenter(MainFragmentPresenterImpl presenter);


}
```

Comment: Please share the _full_ error message (e.g. see [_here_ for some details](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367)). You should check where you use `MainFragmentContract.Presenter`, as it would seem you not only try using it in your `MainFragment`, but also some other place (where you didn't add the module) which is why it will work if you move the binding to a higher level

Answer (score 4):

Obviously, it won't work because if you take a look at your **dependency graph** you'll see that it **doesn't know** how to create an **instance** of **MainFragmentContract.Presenter**.

You have to **connect** it to your **application-level component** by specifying the module which knows how to create the instance of MainFragmentContract.Presenter.

So instead of moving provideMainFragmentPresenter method from my MainFragmentModule to my ActivityBindingModule **do it as follows:**

```
@ApplicationScope
@Component(modules = {
    AndroidInjectionModule.class, 
    ApplicationModule.class,
    NetworkModule.class,
    ActivityBindingModule.class,
    MainFragmentModule.class     //This line right here
})
public interface AppComponent extends AndroidInjector<MyApplication> {

void injectApplication(MyApplication myApplication);

@Component.Builder
interface Builder {
    @BindsInstance
    Builder application(Application application);

    AppComponent build();

 }
}
```