# Got error of Can't be provided without an @Provides-annotated method?

Tags: android, android-room, dagger-2, dagger

Below is my code;

```
@Module
  public class CUModule {

 private FragmentActivity mActivity;

  public CUModule(FragmentActivity activity) {
this.mActivity = activity;

}


 @Singleton
@Provides
Application provideApplication() {
return mActivity.getApplication();
}


@Singleton
@Provides
DeviceUtils proviceDeviceUtils() {
return new DeviceUtils(mActivity);
}

@Singleton
@Provides
AppDatabase provideDatabase (Application application) {
return Room.databaseBuilder(
        application,
        AppDatabase.class,
        "test_database.db"
).build();
}


}
```

**AppDatabase.java**

```
@Database(entities = [Office::class], version = 1)
abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
abstract fun officeDao(): OfficeDao?
}
```

Getting below error while run app,

> [Dagger/MissingBinding] AppDatabase cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.

Comment: Is your application has Dependency Component? I guest some object using AppDatabase but not in scope @Singleton

Comment: Yes it has a dependency component. Can you please explain me what actual means of this error @CôngHải?

Comment: attach Dependency component and parent component code, I will help you

Comment: Please see [here for some general information](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912080/1837367). If you're still stuck after reading this, please update your question with all the necessary information or we'll be guessing blindly